# Need to use ScanResult class in service

Tags: android, android-service

Have some problem to use android.net.wifi.ScanResult class in my own service.
In fact i have noticed that CREATOR in my class is missing, but in android doc (http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/x/android/android/8/p/android.net.wifi/c/ScanResult)
CREATOR is present, i have tried with all versions of SDK and i lose hope... : (

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks,

Anthony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ScanResult class does not have a public constructor. It is intended to be returned from a scan of available WiFi connections, for example:

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if(wifiMgr.isWifiEnabled()) {
  List<ScanResult> scanResults = wifiMgr.getScanResults();
  for(ScanResult scanRes : scanResults) {
    // Do something with scanRes
  }
}
```

Refer to the official [Android documentation for ScanResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html) at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html